# Given any compiled program in Java, is it possible to write a bytecode equivalent version in Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure, bytecode

Clojure operates on the JVM and should theoretically be able to do anything Java can do because of Java interop, but is this really true at the bytecode level? I qualify with bytecode equivalence to emphasize the performance, I assume you may have to skip writing idiomatic code. If this is possible, does this require the use of of a bytecode generating library?

To be more specific, I am interested in the existence of odd corner cases where Java provides constructs that build bytecode in a wildly different manner. I'm not interested in purely language level expressibility, but rather, the progress of clojure's ability to write clojure in clojure, or any new primitive.

Comment: Why would the clojure program have to be bytecode equivalent? From the text of your question it seems like you only care about the effect of the code.

Comment: The trivial answer to the question can "Clojure do everything Java can?" is yes, they are both Turing complete. I'm not certain that is the question you are actually meaning to ask though. Could you perhaps expand on what you mean?

Comment: The question is more specific, regarding bytecode equivalence which is somewhat related to performance as just because a language is equivalently powerful, does not mean that it performs in the same way. Two bytecode equivalent programs should perform identically as well. I understand there is an initial overhead to load all the clojure libraries, but when it comes to the meat of the code, is it possible to get bytecode equivalent code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. To give an example, I don't think there's a way to create an `if` statement in clojure that generate identical bytecode to that of a Java program.

Comment: If you use a library like ASM http://asm.ow2.org/ from clojure, is it then possible?

Answer (score 3):

Clojure programs are always going to have extra runtime baggage which may make them unsuitable for extremely low-resource situations (like Android). But if you don't mind taking a few extra megabytes along for the ride, you can always achieve Java-level performance by throwing convention out the window.

Alex Osborne has a great example of optimizing a Clojure program until it blew the Java competitor away: http://meshy.org/2009/12/13/widefinder-2-with-clojure.html (of course, the same level of attention could have sped up the Java version as well.)

Answer (score 3):

The aim of the nearly complete 1.3 release is to get the important part's (core libraries and collections) to be able to produce byte-code equivalent classes. this is part of the on going clojure-in-clojure goal.

Eventually Clojure should produce **equivalent but not identical byte-code** for everything that has an equivalent in java. Clojure can represent things (like closures) that java does not so of course these will not be "equivalent".

Answer (score 1):

No: Java programs created in Clojure will tend to be a bit larger (in terms of final bytecode size) making it impossible to create bytecode-identical files- Not that this really matters.

In terms of functionality, the Clojure java interop is very good and therefore you can create functionally-equivalent code compared to any Java code, with asymptotically-equivalent performance characteristics. (There may be some extremely, extremely obscure Java features that are not available in Clojure, but I believe java interop in clojure has almost 100% coverage at this point.)

Comment: I'm interested in examples of such obscure Java features. Is it a matter of new jvm ops?